# Android Studio randomly throws exceptions

Tags: android-studio

I've started using Android Studio (ver. 3.1.2) and learning Android development for roughly a week and, ever since day one, the IDE keeps throwing random exceptions just when it feels like it.
None of the exceptions thrown affects my workflow and the IDE keeps working normally (so it seems at least).
The type of the exception may vary from one time to another but the most common is the one below. By looking up online, the results I get are from people who have errors in their code or are using logging libraries.
Neither of those is my case. So why is this happening?

```java
Stub index points to a file without PSI: com.intellij.openapi.fileTypes.UnknownFileType@6e0b0e23
    com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger$EmptyThrowable
        at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:140)
        at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubProcessingHelperBase.processStubsInFile(StubProcessingHelperBase.java:47)
        at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$2.process(StubIndexImpl.java:327)
        at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$StubIdListContainerAction.perform(StubIndexImpl.java:618)
        at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl$StubIdListContainerAction.perform(StubIndexImpl.java:606)
        at com.intellij.util.indexing.ValueContainer.forEach(ValueContainer.java:62)
        at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.doProcessStubs(StubIndexImpl.java:356)
        at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndexImpl.processElements(StubIndexImpl.java:319)
        at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.getElements(StubIndex.java:145)
        at com.intellij.psi.stubs.StubIndex.getElements(StubIndex.java:134)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.java.stubs.index.JavaShortClassNameIndex.get(JavaShortClassNameIndex.java:53)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiShortNamesCacheImpl.getClassesByName(PsiShortNamesCacheImpl.java:63)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.CompositeShortNamesCache.getClassesByName(CompositeShortNamesCache.java:77)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.AllClassesSearchExecutor.lambda$processClassesByNames$1(AllClassesSearchExecutor.java:82)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.lambda$runReadActionInSmartMode$0(DumbService.java:94)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:125)
        at com.intellij.openapi.project.DumbService.runReadActionInSmartMode(DumbService.java:94)
        at com.intellij.psi.impl.search.AllClassesSearchExecutor.processClassesByNames(AllClassesSearchExecutor.java:82)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AllClassesGetter.processJavaClasses(AllClassesGetter.java:150)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AllClassesGetter.processJavaClasses(AllClassesGetter.java:136)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaClassNameCompletionContributor.addAllClasses(JavaClassNameCompletionContributor.java:142)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaNoVariantsDelegator.suggestNonImportedClasses(JavaNoVariantsDelegator.java:186)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JavaNoVariantsDelegator.fillCompletionVariants(JavaNoVariantsDelegator.java:76)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributors(CompletionService.java:83)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:149)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:142)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.JShellCompletionContributor.fillCompletionVariants(JShellCompletionContributor.java:28)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributors(CompletionService.java:83)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:149)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionResultSet.runRemainingContributors(CompletionResultSet.java:142)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.template.impl.LiveTemplateCompletionContributor$2.addCompletions(LiveTemplateCompletionContributor.java:90)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProvider.addCompletionVariants(CompletionProvider.java:36)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionContributor.fillCompletionVariants(CompletionContributor.java:152)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.getVariantsFromContributors(CompletionService.java:83)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionService.performCompletion(CompletionService.java:112)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.calculateItems(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:839)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.access$600(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:92)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator$1CalculateItems.run(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:821)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.tryRunReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:1130)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.tryReadOrCancel(CompletionThreading.java:181)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionProgressIndicator.lambda$startCompletion$6(CompletionProgressIndicator.java:832)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.lambda$null$0(CompletionThreading.java:108)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
        at com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.AsyncCompletion.lambda$startThread$1(CompletionThreading.java:104)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and invalidate cache and restart solved it for me.
`File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`.

Comment: I've done that countless times but it keeps throwing those exceptions. Since I posted this question I also installed the Canary branch (which seems as stable as the Stable branch IMO) and nothing's changed in regard to this question.

Comment: Hmm does it happen to other projects of yours? For me, it was this particular project that had that exception, but as I said after invalidating and restarting, it's OK now.

Comment: jlively, yes. I've only recently got started with Android apps and the book I'm learning from made me create a bunch of new projects already, to explain things better. I'm getting these exceptions in every project I've created so far.